# Chakra with React 18 - Hydration Error for head tag reference

Tags: reactjs, next.js, emotion, chakra-ui

I am trying to figure out how to solve the following errors that come up when I try to use chakra ui with React 18.

> Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI
> does not match what was rendered on the server.
>
> See more info here:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
>
> Unhandled Runtime Error Error: There was an error while hydrating.
> Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire
> root will switch to client rendering.

From what I can make of the hydration error advice, the Head tag needs to be inside a div that is separate from the rest of the content. I tried replacing the fragment tags in this _app.tsx file with a div tag, but I still get the same error.

```
import * as React from "react"
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client"
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import Head from "next/head"

import { useApollo } from "lib/apollo/client"
import { theme } from "lib/theme"

export default function App(props: any) {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props
  const apolloClient = useApollo(pageProps.initialApolloState)
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page: any) => page)
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      </Head>
      <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
        <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>{getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}</ApolloProvider>
      </ChakraProvider>
    </>
  )
}
```

Is there a way to use Chakra UI in a next.js app with React 18.

Comment: Are you using the latest Chakra UI version?

Comment: Hi Camilo - I'm using "@chakra-ui/react": "2.0.0",

Comment: I don't see how is this related to Chakra UI. `Head` is a Next.js component. Btw, there is an official guide for using Chakra UI with Next: https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started/nextjs-guide

Comment: It's a Chakra UI Pro component that im trying to use. The page you have linked has a  n instruction for next 13. I'm using v 12.3.1 so not required to figure out how to accommodate that instruction

Comment: Just skip the `use client` part if you are using Next 12. The rest should be the same.

Comment: But that's why I'm asking the question. I'm using the Chakra UI pro template code. It results in the hydration errors.

Comment: Can you provide a Code Sandbox or similar?

Comment: The reason I didn't do that is that Chakra UI Pro sells its code as templates. I don't like to share it publicly when that is the product it sells. If you use Chakra UI Pro, all I have done is copied and pasted its code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try waiting for the `router` to hydrate the page.

```
const router = useRouter();
const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

useEffect(() => {
  if (router.isReady) {
    setLoading(false);
  }
}, [router.isReady]);

return <> {loading ? <div>Loading...</div> : <...your JSX>} </>
```